# Is "most good" ever correct?

Tags: word-usage

I'm in the process of filling in the "About me" section on another SE site. When I was reading/reviewing it before posting, I noticed a construct that I had used and that I'm not entirely sure is correct, but seems to me most appropriate in that context.

Here's a snippet of the sentence I had written, followed by my question and reasoning:

> ... But ultimately, I had to come back to the thing I was most good at ...

**Is the use of "most good" ever correct?**

I know *most good* is just a dumb way of saying *best*, but I don't feel like *best* is the best option in this context (not even the "most good" option). Using *best* here, at least to me, sounds like I'm *the* best at the thing, implying that I'm better than other people are at that thing (for clarity's sake, that thing is programming.)

What I meant by writing that sentence is that out of all the things I did, programming was the one I was the **most good** at. I think using *best* would lose the intended meaning of the sentence. So that's why I chose *most good* instead of *best*, and now I just want to know whether or not it's correct to use (grammatically or otherwise).

In school when we were learning English, *most good* was often used as a joke to point out someone's bad English. Google search was pretty much useless as usual, the closest to a "definition" was an urban-dictionary entry, which funnily enough gave the same definition that I used here. A search on the ELU site didn't yield much either, so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Under some circumstances, it doesn't sound bad (like this one). I'm sure many circumstances it sounds awful though. "You're dong the most good you can do" where 'good' is meant as a noun, is very acceptable sounding. 'gooder' and 'goodest' are awful no matter what.

Comment: *Best at* does not mean *the best at*, in the same way that *my best friend* is not the best friend in the world - just the best of my friends.

Comment: I see where you're going, but I'd still use _best_.

Comment: In my situation, a simple comment is the option that does the most good.

Comment: @Davo I take it that I should maybe reword the question a bit? I meant "good" as an adjective and not a noun, but didn't clarify that anywhere because I thought it'd be clear enough from the context.

Comment: In some contexts "most good" means the same as "best".  But, generally speaking, "best" is gooder.

Comment: @matronator - if you want to know about "most good" as an adjective, that's what the actual question should be. Your context is explicit, but the wording of the question (in bold and in the title) is not. This is just a suggestion. The actual title attracts viewers (and leads to answers).

Comment: @HotLicks Goodly said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's sometimes fine. It is understandable, does not violate any grammar conventions, and in some cases is even preferable to "best". For example, when it is in series with other phrases that use "most", we may want to maintain parallelism:

> The hero is the most good, law-abiding, and brave character in the entire book.

Because we must say "most law-abiding" (not "law-abidingest"), the principle of parallelism suggests that we should use "most" for the entire series. (Of course, it may be preferable to re-word this sentence, avoiding the problem entirely, but that's another issue.)

Comment: Yes. 'Good' [adj] is polysemous, and 'most good' seems better than 'best' for some subsenses.

Answer (score 0):

The word [good](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good) can be used as three different parts of speech.  Noun, adjective, and adverb.

It's used adjectivally most often.

> This soup is good.

It's less frequently used as a noun.

> I do this for the common good.

And, the adverbial use is largely informal, typically used in place of the more formal *well*.

> I didn't sleep very good last night.
>   I didn't sleep very well last night.

When using the modifier *most* in front of good, it's usually found when good is used as a noun.

> He preferred to donate money where he thought it would do the most good.

The usage of most in front of adverbial *good* will tend to sound EXTREMELY informal.  (In fact, to my ear it has a dialectical quality to it that makes me think of Southern US English.)

> I sleep most good on my side.

The majority of people would substitute the word *best* for this usage.

Unfortunately, despite what many people will tell you, **there is no such thing as correct** when it comes to language.  Language is a tool that intends to express ideas in a manner that other people can understand.  Therefore, if you are able to communicate your idea in an understandable way, it is correct.  There is, to my knowledge, no single compendium of the English language and its grammatical rules that can be pointed to as authoritative above all else.  There are many manuals of style that purport to tell you how best to write and speak.  But, again, these represent mere suggestions of propriety.

So, instead, we rely upon perceived formality and propriety to dictate our best usage.  The result is that certain usages become preferred to others due to their perception as "correct" in common usage.  Phrases tend to cycle in and out of favor despite their correctness.

So the short answer:  Yes, it can be used correctly. But, no that doesn't guarantee that it will be perceived as formal.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not the concept of "correct" exists, hearing someone use "good" as an adverb makes my skin crawl.

Comment: @IsabelArcher Skin crawl aside, it's still not wrong.  It's just not what you prefer.

Comment: As I recall, @David M, that is exactly what I said. It is distinctly what I do not prefer.

Comment: A lot of this is irrelevant (especially following OP's 'I meant "good" as an adjective and not a noun, but didn't clarify that anywhere because I thought it'd be clear enough from the context'). And you fail to address the actual question, the use of 'most good' for adjectival 'best': _the thing I'm good / excellent / poor / worst / best / ??most good at_.